# Echo current custom post types assosiated taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm stuck on trying to retrieve a custom post types associated taxonomy category. This is where I have got to, could do with a pointer. It currently returns all taxonomys associated with the custom post type.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'title_li' => __( '' ),
        'taxonomy' => 'client',
    );
?>

<h6><?php echo wp_list_categories( $args ); ?></h6>
```

Comment: Just so I understand this, you're trying to list all terms assigned to a post or all terms in a taxonomy?

Comment: Howdy mcgee, attached to my custom post type 'Projects' I have the taxonomy 'clients' for example 'BBC'. However the above code is pulling in all available categories from within my site. Within the taxonomy 'clients' there is BBC, C4, ITV etc. these are the ones I wish to display.

ie. Newsnight is on BBC, so that should be displayed not BBC + ITV etc.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code for showing all the category of the custom taxonomy : client : only.

```
$categories = get_terms( 'client', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
 ) );
print_r($categories);
```

It will display the category of client taxonomy only.
Thanking you.

Comment: Hey there buddy, can you confirm I have got this correct with your help above:

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     $categories = get_terms( 'client', array(
         'orderby'    => 'count',
         'hide_empty' => 0,
      ) );
     print_r($categories);
    ?>
   <h6><?php echo wp_list_categories( $categories ); ?></h6>